# What is the probability that exactly one of the dice shows 0

Tags: probability, probability-theory

3 Dice:

2 Green dice with faces labelled 0,0,1,1,2,2

1 red die with faces labelled 1,2,3,4,5,6

2 are chosen at random and then thrown.

What is the probability that exactly one shows 0.

So either there are 2 green dice (P = 1/3)

OR there is one red dice and one green (P = 2/3)

with the one red/green could you say (2/3)(2/6) because there is only 0's in the green dice

but then with the green/green cases, how do you ensure that only one die has a 0

Comment: $2$ green dice has probability $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Thanks. I just typed it wrong. I knew that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In two out of the three cases we pick a Green and a Red die. (Chance $2/3$)
Then, we only have a die with zeros in it so we just need it to show it. (Chance $2/6$). So the total chance for this case is $\frac{2}{3}·\frac{2}{6} = \frac{2}{9}$

In the remaining case, wich chance $1/3$, one has to show a zero and the other one must not:
The chance to show it is $2/6$ and the chance for not showing one is $4/6$. So the chance for the first die to show a zero and the second not to is $\frac{1}{3}·\frac{2}{6}·\frac{4}{6} = \frac{2}{27}$, but we can also have the first one not to show a zero and the second one to do so, so the chance in this case is doubled: $\frac{4}{27}$.

We just have to add up the chances:

$$\frac{2}{9} + \frac{4}{27} = \frac{10}{27}$$

Comment: yes. I was just about to ask about the 1/3 but you edited. This is the correct answer and now I know how you got there :)

Comment: my problem was I didn't consider the swapping around first and second

Comment: Yeah, it's a common mistake when you have two identical items.

Answer (score 1):

Add up the probabilities of the following independent events:

- Choose green die $A$ and red die, then get $0$ on green die: $\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{2}{6}$
- Choose green die $B$ and red die, then get $0$ on green die: $\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{2}{6}$
- Choose green dice $A$ and $B$, then get $0$ on $A$ and $1$ or $2$ on $B$: $\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{2}{6}\cdot\dfrac{4}{6}$
- Choose green dice $A$ and $B$, then get $0$ on $B$ and $1$ or $2$ on $A$: $\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{2}{6}\cdot\dfrac{4}{6}$

Hence the probability of exactly one die showing $0$ is $\dfrac{1}{9}+\dfrac{1}{9}+\dfrac{2}{27}+\dfrac{2}{27}=\dfrac{10}{27}$

Answer (score 1):

If $E$ denotes the event
that exactly one of the dice shows $0$, then:

$P\left(E\right)=P\left(E\mid RG\right)P\left(RG\right)+P\left(E\mid GG\right)P\left(GG\right)=\frac{2}{6}\frac{2}{3}+(\frac{2}{6}\frac{4}{6}+\frac{4}{6}\frac{2}{6})\frac{1}{3}$

Do you understand why?

Comment: Yes. Darth Geek explained it pretty well.